# Customer Login, Products and Place Order REST APIs for React Native from an existing Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token

I've figured out how to login using customer credentials and get the token. I'm not able to fetch the products, categories with this token. Do I really need an admin token? Is it not safe to expose this admin token in my code?

Comment: Please add what issue are you facing. What error does it throws ? It will be helpful for community to help you out with more details.

Comment: which endpoints do you need, precisely?